# What does colon mean when used as an argument in the debug module for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, debugging

What does it mean when you pass an argument to the debug module that contains a colon?

For example:

`var debug = require('debug')('botkit:get_app_id');`

Comment: That doesn't belong to the `require`, it's simply an arbitrary argument to whatever function the `require` call returned.

Comment: `require('debug')` returns a function, you are passing in the string 'botkit:get_app_id' to that function.

Comment: gotcha. in that case, what does it mean in the context of debug?

Comment: In this case, it tells debug what stuff to output debug-info about.  Try passing in wildcard `'*'` if you are feeling brave.

Comment: what I'm confused about is, do it pass in wildcard in my code or at the command line when I start my bot?